# Why does this OR Statement in A WHERE clause that has 2 conditions not run

Tags: sql, postgresql

The result set list on the below query is empty. Using AND to create a more complex condition within there WHERE clause

```
SELECT 
    date,
    -- Identify the home team as Barcelona or Real Madrid
    CASE WHEN hometeam_id = 8634 THEN 'FC Barcelona' 
         ELSE 'Real Madrid CF' END AS home,
    -- Identify the away team as Barcelona or Real Madrid
    CASE WHEN awayteam_id = 8634 THEN 'FC Barcelona' 
         ELSE 'Real Madrid CF' END AS away
FROM matches_spain
WHERE (awayteam_id = 8634 AND hometeam_id = 8634)
      OR (awayteam_id = 8633 AND hometeam_id = 8633);
```

This is the schema of the table

```
matches_spain
id
country_id
season
stage
date
hometeam_id
awayteam_id
home_goal
away_goal
```

Yet this works.

```
SELECT 
    date,
    -- Identify the home team as Barcelona or Real Madrid
    CASE WHEN hometeam_id = 8634 THEN 'FC Barcelona' 
         ELSE 'Real Madrid CF' END AS home,
    -- Identify the away team as Barcelona or Real Madrid
    CASE WHEN awayteam_id = 8634 THEN 'FC Barcelona' 
         ELSE 'Real Madrid CF' END AS away
FROM matches_spain
WHERE (awayteam_id = 8634 OR hometeam_id = 8634)
      AND (awayteam_id = 8633 OR hometeam_id = 8633);
```

Comment: Impossible to answer without data.

Comment: Well, they're, you know, different queries? `(A AND B) OR (C AND D)` is simply not logically equivalent to `(A OR B) AND (C OR D)`.

Comment: By the way, this is unlikely to be correct: awayteam_id = 8634 AND hometeam_id = 8634. Teams don't play against themself.

Comment: intuitively, the same team can't be both the away team AND the home team..

Comment: hometeam and awayteam can never be the same so the first would produce no results

Comment: Essentially you don't have any one record in your table where the away team is 8634 and the home team is 8634 (the same team, so not surprising). You also don't have any single record where the away team is 8633 and the home team is 8633. That's why your first query returns no results.

Comment: Hardcoding id values in a query is most probably the wrong way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that a `WHERE` clause is conceptually testing *each single row of data* against the condition.

The condition `awayteam_id = 8634 AND hometeam_id = 8634` will be true only for rows where *both* the `awayteam_id` *and* the `hometeam_id` are `8634`.

To visualise with examples:

| awayteam_id | hometeam_id | awayteam_id = 8634 AND hometeam_id = 8634 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8001 | 8002 | false |
| 8001 | 8634 | false |
| 8634 | 8002 | false |
| 8634 | 8634 | true |

By the names of the columns, I'm guessing that the table represents sports matches between two teams. If that's the case, the last row would represent a team playing against themselves.

If you don't have any matches like that, then you won't get any rows matching that condition.